# About Dynamic Analytics ID during gradle build

Tags: android, google-analytics, android-gradle-plugin

So, today I've faced with a problem, where I would like to set up a dynamic gradle build, where I can include two Google Analytics key: one for the debug and one for the live environment. 
I tried the following solution, what did not work:

```
        release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        resValue "string", "googleAnalyticsID", "UA-666666-1"
    }
    debug {
        buildConfigField "Boolean", "DEBUG_MODE", "true"
        versionNameSuffix "-Demo"

        resValue "string", "googleAnalyticsID", "UA-777777-1"

    }
```

If I'm able to replace the ID, how can I replace the google-services.json file? I hope I don't need to copy it with a script.

I'm looking forward to hear you ideas, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

So far, this is what I've figured out, but I think this is not the best answer, still don't know who to operate with the JSON

```
       if (BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE.contains("debug")) {
        tracker = analytics.newTracker("UA-66807305-1");
    } else {
        tracker = analytics.newTracker("UA-66499744-1");
    }
```